# How to select the fields that i want to show in DRF using a foreign key

Tags: python, django

I'm working on a small project using Django / Rest Framework, i have two models ( CustomUser and Team )

```
from django.db import models
from users.models import CustomUser


class Team(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

This is my serializer :

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from apps.teams.models import Team

    
class TeamSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Team
        fields = '__all__'  # how can i show the CustomUser model fields
        depth = 1
```

the result is :

```
[
    {
        "id": 3,
        "user": {
            "id": 8,
            "password": "",
            "last_login": null,
            "is_superuser": false,
            "is_staff": false,
            "is_active": true,
            "date_joined": "2021-05-04T21:23:46.513567Z",
            "first_name": "John",
            "last_name": "Doe",
            "username": "testingxe",
            "email": "ab@test.com",
            "groups": [],
            "user_permissions": []
        }
    }
]
```

how can i choose the user, fields that i want to show /  i can't show all of them because i have the password ...

Comment: in `fields` you can select what you want to add. You can add everything or you can add only the fields you want there to display in the endpoint.

Comment: sorry, but no way if i want to select another fields from another table ( foreignkey)

Comment: You just add what is specified on the model. you can have two fields one called `user` and other called `manager` from your team model. then you just has to add the name into your team serializer: fields = ['user', 'manager']. that's all.

Comment: @EliasPrado thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to use nested serializers like so:

```py
class UserSerializer(...):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['first_name', 'last_name', ...]


class TeamSerializer(...):
    user = UserSerializer(many=False)
    class Meta:
        model = Team
        fields = ['user', ...]
```

Comment: TypeError at /api/teams/
'CustomUser' object is not iterable

Comment: Ah - you set up your models so you can only have 1 user per team, so change many to `False` - see my edit.